# I am updating angular version from 4 to 7 and i am facing this issue

Tags: angular

Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "7.2.15".

*package.json*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng2-select2": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.1",
    "select2": "4.0.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "~2.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^8.3.21",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/select2": "4.0.35",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.5.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^1.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Are you following the instructions in the guide? https://update.angular.io/#4.0:7.2, I had just done a 4 to 6 upgrade about 2 months ago.

Comment: Hallo and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then put some effort into formulating your question so others may understand where exactly you need help and you will see people are much more willing to offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

Add dev dependency for `@angular/compiler-cli`

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli@<your angular version>
```